# MERGE working directly on Oracle but not going through when used via JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using following SQL in my java code:

```
String mergePositionsSQL = "MERGE INTO holding h " +
                "USING (SELECT :acct_no as acct_no_param, :brand as brand_param, :cusip as cusip_param FROM DUAL) du " +
                "ON (h.acct_no = du.acct_no_param AND h.brand = du.brand_param AND h.cusip = du.cusip_param) " +
                "WHEN MATCHED THEN " +
                "UPDATE SET "+  
                "h.qty = :qty, h.tdate = :tradeDate, h.settlement = :settleDate, " + 
                "h.acq_price = :acqPrice, h.acq_yield = :acqYield " +
                "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " +
                "INSERT (h.acct_no, h.brand, h.cusip, h.qty, h.tdate, h.settlement, h.acq_price, h.acq_yield) " +
                "VALUES " +
                "(:acct_no,:brand,:cusip,:qty,:tradeDate,:settleDate,:acqPrice,:acqYield)";
```

When I run this Query on Toad it works as expected but when I execute it via JDBC it stucks and never do anything. What can be wrong here ?

Also, is there a alternate way to accomplish this construct safely in Oracle i.e insert when record does not exist and update it when exist.

This is the code that runs this query:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("acct_no", accountNumber);
            parameters.put("brand", brand);
            parameters.put("cusip", position.getCusip());
            parameters.put("qty", position.getQty());
            parameters.put("tradeDate", position.getTradeDate());
            parameters.put("settleDate", position.getSettleDate());
            parameters.put("acqPrice", position.getAcqPrice());
            parameters.put("acqYield", position.getAcqYield());
jdbc.update(mergePositionsSQL, parameters);
```

I am using Spring JDBC in the above code.

Comment: you need to post your code and the errors you are getting. you have bound variables here , like ":acct_no" and when you run them via JDBC you need to set their values. without seeing your code we can't know what you are doing.

Comment: code added , please have a look at it.

Comment: not familiar with spring. i searched about NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and your code seems to be fine. If it is not giving an error, I can only suggest that you check if the changes are being committed. I have no I idea how spring handles transactions and when commit happens so I am sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have an open transaction pending in your DB workbench (in your case Toad) against the same table. If so, it could be causing the requests from your JDBC client to be blocked. Commit or discard the transaction in Toad and try again.